# What is the proper way to use ISOLINUX with UEFI?

Tags: boot, uefi, iso, syslinux

I've been trying to add UEFI support in the 64-bit version of [Minimal Linux Live](http://minimal.linux-bg.org) for quite some time, unfortunately without much success. As you can see from the below image, I get **critical error** each time I try to boot via UEFI.

[image: Minimal Linux Live - UEFI]

This is what I did in order to get to this point:

1. I downloaded [syslinux-6.0.3](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/boot/syslinux).
2. I followed the instructions [here](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Install#UEFI) and copied `efi64/efi/syslinux.efi` to `\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI`.
3. I also copied `efi64/com32/elflink/ldlinux/ldlinux.e64` to `\EFI\BOOT\LDLINUX.E64`.
4. I created virtual machine in [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org) (version 5.0.20) and enabled UEFI.
5. I generated new ISO image (all ISOLINUX configuration files are in the root folder, see the screenshot) and put it as primary bootable media in the virtual machine.
6. After boot I immediately got the error which you see on the screenshot.
7. At this point I had to rename `\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI` to `\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX641.EFI` in order to "break" the boot process and fall back to UEFI shell.
8. In the UEFI shell I used the command `edit` and then I navigated to the `\EFI\BOOT` folder.
9. I manually invoked `BOOTX641.EFI` and I ended up with the same error which you can see.

So, I can conclude that my EFI stub is getting executed but something breaks during the execution process and at this point I don't know what's wrong.

I checked the ISO image structure of [System Rescue CD](http://system-rescue-cd.org) which I know that supports UEFI and I noticed the following:

1. The EFI structure contains only one file: `\efi\boot\bootx64.efi`.
2. The size of `\efi\boot\bootx64.efi` is 724KB while the corresponding file in Syslinux 6.03 `efi64/efi/syslinux.efi` is ~200KB so this is definitely not the same file.
3. When I copied `\efi\boot\bootx64.efi` from "System Rescue CD" and used it in the EFI structure in "Minimal Linux Live" the UEFI boot process was fine to the point where I was presented with GRUB 2 shell.

That's how I found out that the file `\efi\boot\bootx64.efi` in "System Rescue CD" has built-in GRUB 2 support, therefore it must be a custom built solution.

So, the problem in just few words - I'm using vanilla Syslinux package and I'd like to create UEFI compatible configuration which boots a simple ISO image. Following the official instructions doesn't seem to work for me.

All suggestions are highly appreciated! Thank you!

---

**Note 1:** The ISO image boots fine in BIOS mode. There is no problem there.

**Note 2:** Most probably this is not a bug in VirtualBox because other operating systems (e.g. Ubuntu and Linux Mint) boot just fine in UEFI mode.

---

**EDIT 1 - (Jan-2017):**

It has been very long time without answer, so I implemented my solution in quite different way:

- I don't use `Syslinux` in UEFI boot mode.
- I compiled my Linux kernel with EFI stub.
- I created simple `startup.nsh` script which is executed automatically after UEFI boot.
- The same script loads the kernel and the initramfs.

In this way I lose some of the boot functionality, e.g. `vga=ask` which works fine in `Syslinux` but it doesn't work in UEFI mode since this particular boot option requires proper Linux boot loader.

Even though I have solution which works fine, the question is still open.

**EDIT 2 - (Dec-2017):**

This is in addition to the previous update. The solution with `startup.nsh` works only if the UEFI system has 'UEFI Shell' (according to the UEFI specs the firmware may or may not provide shell) and only if this shell has support level 1 or above. Also, there is no guarantee that the startup script will be executed, because the proper way to provide ESP in ISO image is via 'El Torito' boot image. Providing ESP compatible structure directly on the ISO image seems to work fine on certain firmwares but it is not universal solution.

The question is still open but meanwhile I managed to integrate [systemd-boot](https://github.com/ivandavidov/systemd-boot) and I no longer consider this issue as high priority.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds more like System Rescue CD uses GRUB, not syslinux.  My grub64.efi is about 1MB, but I imagine you can build it with fewer modules included.

The image you copied is called syslinux.efi, so I would not call it isolinux.  I expect it looks for a file called `syslinux.cfg`, not `isolinux.cfg`.  (isolinux will fall back to `syslinux.cfg` though).

I also notice you say "all ISOLINUX configuration files are in the root folder".  I can't tell how you created the ISO.  Remember that the bootloader needs to be in a [special boot image](http://wiki.osdev.org/El-Torito#Hybrid_Setup_for_BIOS_and_EFI_from_CD.2FDVD_and_USB_stick), not the directory tree you see if you mount the iso9660 filesystem.  Obviously VirtualBox is booting something so that's not the problem here, but if it's more permissive than other systems then you might still be doing the "wrong" thing.

The hybrid boot images set up by "several popular Linux distributions" are highly entertaining to read about, but the last I read it wasn't quite possible to have a single image supporting all of Mac, 32-bit EFI... there are at least firmwares that see multiple of the boot images and ask the user to choose between "1" and "2".  Just a note before anyone tries going down the rabbit hole, at least with the Mac-specific support, it might be safer only to implement the parts you're able to test.

Comment: Yes, in UEFI mode it's hard to say where the "efi" file comes from, so most probably "System Resue CD" uses GRUB 2 as main boot loader in UEFI mode without using Syslinux/ISOLINUX at all.

Comment: You can see how I create the ISO image file [here](https://github.com/ivandavidov/minimal/blob/master/src/12_generate_iso.sh).

Note that this is the original source code, without the UEFI stuff. I'm using only the stuff which comes from Syslinux, nothing more. Also, according to the Syslinux specs the structure is valid - you can use the root folder as main configuration folder.

I already tried to rename the configuration file and use `syslinux` instead of `isolinux`. I even tried to place the conf files in `syslinux` folder inside the `efi` folder (read it somewhere), still no success.

Comment: It looks like Ubuntu on EFI also used GRUB, at least in some versions https://help.ubuntu.com/communityUEFI#Identifying_if_the_computer_boots_the_Ubuntu_DVD_in_EFI_mode  Can you confirm that successfully booting CD(s) in Virtualbox are booting the EFI version of syslinux?

Comment: Nope, seems like `Linux Mint`, `Ubuntu` and `Arch Linux`, as well as `System Rescue CD` are all running UEFI versions of GRUB 2.

The closest thing I found is using [Syslinux on EFI partition for HDD installation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/syslinux.html) but this is quite different from my case since I have ISO image with live Linux OS. Anyway, I tried this approach and the result I get is the same **critical error**.